# Databases design and primary key composed

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a table named minibar_bill and i use it for keeping evidence of client's expenditure. I'm trying to build a hotel/pension system management.

I thought that i could make a table

Minibar_bill with (id_bill, id_minibar_product, id_client)

And i would like to add those info on an invoice based on bill_id...

How should i do it ?

I mean i want to have something like that:

```
Id_bill(1)
id_minibar_product(1,2,3)
id_client(123)
```

So first 3 records will be :

```
1, 1, 123
1, 2, 123
1, 3, 123
```

And i want the id_bill to be on invoice ... maybe i could switch id_product with id_bill

Where id_bill(1) - would be the first bill record in database
id_minibar_product(1,2,3) - would be product 1,2,3 which has been consumed by client
id_client(123) - client id which we use on invoice to collect data from Client table in order to print them on invoice( i will use C# for UI ).

What I have tried:

I've tried to make a db with field id_bill and id_product but i think it's a wrong approach since i made them a composed primary key and i cannot add them to foreign key in Invoice table.

Comment: You've made just about every design mistake you could here. Take a look at this one: http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/modeling-a-database-for-recording-sales-part-1. If you are still around and do not abandon the question I will pose an answer explaining some of the design issues here

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I took a look at that one ... The problem is that i do not find a solution to have a better design ... even if i post my table names, they are in romanian language ... and you will not understand very much ... 

The problem i face is that i have the following tables Invoice, Room, Minibar, Minibar_bill and Minibar_products.

What i wish for is to link Invoice to minibar_bill in order to have the status on a single Invoice of all products from minibar which have been bought by a customer...

Comment: if you are interested in learning search for "invoicing in ms access" in google there are plenty of examples and tutorials which will help you.
here one: http://web.pdx.edu/~gerbing/325/Resources/Access.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for your design:

It's a good idea to name things descriptively, *but* if you create a table called `Minibar_bill`, that's going to be inconsistent and short sighted if  you want to start charging in-room movies and in-room dining, services etc. to the room. I suggest you call it something more generic - remove Minibar from all of your table names.

You must never put comma separated values into a single field.

There are a million sales data models online, including, as already suggested, templates in MS Access. There's no point reinventing the wheel

I suggest you have something like this

```
Client                  A list of clients
Products                A list of products you can be billed for (not just minibar)
Bill                    A client has zero or more bills (usually one)
BillLine                A bill has zero ore more lines. Each line represents 
                        One product being charged for on a bll
```

So `Bill` is the header. It's up to you whether you add a column indicating when / if it is invoiced, paid etc., or whether you want to create a seperate invoicing module.

With regards to this comment:

> > What i wish for is to link Invoice to minibar_bill in order to have the status on a single Invoice of all products from minibar which have been bought by a customer.

If you have a seperate invoice table you can write the `BillID` to it to link it.

I'm not sure if you understand that all this info exists across different tables, and when, for example, you print an invoice, you go and collect all the info from across the tables at that time.